# React hooks - how to access ...other spread and also a named property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In an older class I have the following;

```
class ComponentItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { item, ...other } = this.props;
    return (
      <>...</>
    )
  }
};
```

Now I want to refactor and use hooks, but how can I access the named properties, and the "other properties inside a hook?

I tried

```
const ComponentItem = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { item, ...other } = props;

  return (
   <>...</>
  )
}
```

```
const ComponentItem = (item, ...other) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(item); // takes all passed in props
  console.log(...other);

  return (
   <>...</>
  )
}
```

What is the best way to do this in a function using hooks?

Comment: It should be `const ComponentItem = ({ item, ...other }) => {...}` - this is just a functional component that takes `props` as the argument, so you have to `destruct` the first argument rather than expecting two separate arguments. Hooks have nothing to do with it - at least in the way you present it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using the rest parameters, like the following:

```
const ComponentItem = ({item, ...others}) => {
  return <>
     { /* return of component */ }
  </>
}
```

Read further here: [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the component with [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (the equivalent of PureComponent), and destructure the components props in params:

```
const ComponentItem = React.memo(({ item, ...other }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
   <>...</>
  )
})
```